# How to get result from FtpCommand API

Tags: c++, api, ftp, ftp-client

this is MSDN code for creating FTP Command

BOOL FtpCommand(

*In*   HINTERNET hConnect,

*In*   BOOL fExpectResponse,

*In*   DWORD dwFlags,

*In*   LPCTSTR lpszCommand,

*In*   DWORD_PTR dwContext,

*Out*  HINTERNET *phFtpCommand

);

But I don't know how to use the response.

For example: if I send "LIST" [to get list of files & directories I set lpszCommand=LIST] I don't know how can I save it to a file or in a variable.
At all there is no good example to showing use of parameters of this function in practice.